# require file using phar stream does not work within ZendStudio

Tags: php, zend-studio, zend-debugger, phar

I am struggeling with a quite strange problem within ZendStudio. Including or requiring files inside a phar archive using the phar extensions phar:// stream wrapper will not work from within ZendStudio.

Here is what I have done.

Given the following file structure:

```
phar/Test.php
pharbuilder.php
usephar.php
```

With the following content:

phar/Test.php:

```php
class Test {}
```

pharbuilder.php:

```php
$phar = new Phar(__DIR__ . '/test.phar');
$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__ . '/phar/');
```

usephar.php:

```php
var_dump(file_exists('phar://' . __DIR__ . '/test.phar/Test.php'));
include('phar://' . __DIR__ . '/test.phar/Test.php');
$test = new Test();
var_dump($test);
```

Now, if you first run the pharbuilder.php in ZendStudio (ZS 8: right click on file, run as PHP Script) the phar file (test.phar) will be successfully created (before running it, you have to add the ini option `phar.readonly=0` to the corresponding php.ini). However, running the usephar.php inside ZS, will result in an error.

```
bool(true)
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar:///somepath/test.phar/Test.php' for inclusion
```

So obviously, the file can be found, but it cannot be included. I can also access the content of the Test.php within the file using `file_get_contents('phar://' . __DIR__ . '/test.phar/Test.php')`

Also, I noticed that this will not happen, if I modify the run configuration for this script and disable the checkbox "Display debug information when running". So I assume it has something to do with the ZendDebugger, but I'm not quite sure.

When I run the same scripts from a console, everything works just fine.

I tried this with ZendStudio 8 and 10 and with all in ZS provided php versions (5.4.11, 5.3.21, 5.3.3 all in CGI and CLI).

Since I could not find anybody else with the same problem, I assume that I am doing something wrong and am open to any suggestions. Maybe some secret php.ini directive or something like this.

Comment: i would create a support ticket with zend on this one.

Comment: My colleague used his zend contact and they could reproduce the problem. Hopefully they will fix it soon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Were you able to fix this in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed in [Zend Studio](https://www.zend.com/products/zend-studio) 10.6.2.
Please mind that as mentioned above you need to modify `php.ini` file (located in -`<studio_home>/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32.x86_\resources\php`)
and add
`phar.readonly=0`